# Where to find Windows Modern UI apps' source code?

Tags: windows, windows-8, modern-ui, source-code

As an amateur web developer I'm intrested in building native apps for Windows 8 with `HTML5` and `CSS`. But It would be nice to see the source code of the apps that I have and which language they are written in.

Where can I find that source code? Or is it even available? I mean some of the apps must be open source?

Comment: Search the web for the apps, if they're open source surely you'll find them on sourceforge, github, even codeplex or similar?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can find the source code for some of the apps in: (There's probably another folder since this isn't all the apps I have)

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps
```

---

For those of you who do not have permissions to access the folder follow these instructions:

1. Type in “C:\Program Files\Applications” in the Windows Explorer address bar and hit enter.
   [image]
2. Observe in shock and dismay the system dialogue saying you don’t own a folder on your own machine. Hit “Continue”.
   [image]
3. After hitting “Continue”, you’ll be confronted by the following dialogue:
   [image]
   Do not hit “close”, instead click the “security tab” link.
4. In the following system dialogue click “advanced”.
   [image]
5. Click the “change” link in the owner security field.
   [image]
6. Add in your live ID or windows 8 user name to the “select user or group” system dialogue.
   [image]
7. Click “OK”, Click “OK”, Click “Ok”.
   [image]

Credits: [Justin Angel](http://justinangel.net/ReverseEngineerWin8Apps)

Comment: I can't get access to it. Even though I'm logged in as administrator.

Comment: Yeah you'll have to set ownership permissions for that. For the time being look at this link while I update my answer: http://justinangel.net/ReverseEngineerWin8Apps

Answer (score 1):

You can get examples of metro/modernui/window store app code [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-Modern-Style-App-Samples) from MS's code snippet site - there's more [specific samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=User&f%5B0%5D.Value=Official%20Windows%20SDK%20Sample) here. And of course, how to do hello world [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986964.aspx). They seem to cover a good range of things and unless you specifically want to have a modified version of say, the mail app, are probably easier to make use of

Why get the apple from the barrel, when you can get it from the tree?

Answer (score 1):

There is a free e-book from Microsoft press for programming windows 8 apps using HTML 5, CSS and JavaScript. It includes a download for source code.

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/microsoft_press/free-ebook-programming-windows-8-apps-with-html-css-and-javascript-second-preview)

Answer (score 0):

Since the question [How to get access to C:\Program Files\WindowsApps?](https://superuser.com/q/498774/116475) was marked as a dupe, I'll add another solution to get access to `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps`, from [https://www.maketecheasier.com](https://www.maketecheasier.com/access-windowsapps-folder-windows-10/):

Save the following as a `.reg` file and run it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; MajorGeeks.Com
; How To Take Full Ownership of Files & Folders
; https://www.majorgeeks.com/content/page/take_full_ownership_of_files_folders.html

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\runas]
@="Take Ownership"
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /c takeown /f \"%1\" && icacls \"%1\" /grant administrators:F"
"IsolatedCommand"="cmd.exe /c takeown /f \"%1\" && icacls \"%1\" /grant administrators:F"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas]
@="Take Ownership"
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""
E
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /c takeown /f \"%1\" /r /d y && icacls \"%1\" /grant administrators:F /t"
"IsolatedCommand"="cmd.exe /c takeown /f \"%1\" /r /d y && icacls \"%1\" /grant administrators:F /t"
```

then open MS Explorer, right click on `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps` and select “Take Ownership.”. It'll show:

[image]

then you can access `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps`.

Notes:

- I had to reboot my Windows 10 PC before being able to see https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIL7M.png
- For Win 11 users, [https://www.maketecheasier.com](https://www.maketecheasier.com/access-windowsapps-folder-windows-10/) says:

  > If you do not see the Take Ownership option in Windows 11, click “show more” to see its availability in [Windows 11 context menus](https://www.maketecheasier.com/windows-11-context-menus/).

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/0Nt2mmk.png Is that right?

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle I guess a typo, the script works though, I've just used it.