# How to get access to C:\Program Files\WindowsApps?

Tags: windows, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where to find Windows 8 Modern UI apps source code?](https://superuser.com/questions/498768/where-to-find-windows-8-modern-ui-apps-source-code)

How do I open the folder `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps`?

Currently I'm denied to enter, even though I'm logged in as *administrator*.

Comment: I already answered this question in your old question.

Comment: Well, as it isn't correct to ask questions in the comments. And I considered this question as important. Search engins will easier find this post rather then the answer in that comment. And the post where you described how to do it was edited after I made posted this.

Comment: @AlfredLarsson: That's actually the reason why we close questions as duplicates; to make it easier for people who use search engines to find a specific information.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

1. Type in `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps` in the Windows Explorer address bar and hit enter.

   [image: Enter path]
2. Observe in shock and dismay the system dialog saying you don’t own a folder on your own machine. Hit "Continue."

   [image: Denied]
3. After hitting "Continue," you’ll be confronted by the following dialog:

   [image: Denied again]

   Do not hit "Close"—instead click the "security tab" link.
4. In the following system dialog click "Advanced."

   [image: Properties]
5. Click the "Change" link in the owner security field.

   [image: Change]
6. Add in your Live ID or Windows 8 user name to the "Select User or Group" system dialog.

   [image: Add user]
7. Click "OK," "OK," and "OK."

   [image: Done]

Credits: [Justin Angel](http://justinangel.net/ReverseEngineerWin8Apps)

Comment: Do you know if it could be dangerous to get access to this folder? Will it be easier for virus to gain access to this folder when I change this?

Comment: If a virus gets on to your computer it makes no difference if it gives them easier access, your whole computer is already compromised. The reason micrososft does this is so that normal users don't tamper with the apps and then complain to Microsoft about them not working.

Comment: If you want to revert this ownership change, instructions are [here](http://www.askvg.com/guide-how-to-restore-trustedinstaller-as-default-owner-of-a-file-or-folder-in-windows/)

Comment: How to turn it back like before ?

Answer (score 2):

The ownership of the files belongs to "TrustedInstaller". You can change the owner to your current user. [Here's a page describing how to do that.](http://justinangel.net/ReverseEngineerWin8Apps)