# Editing/Creating files in C:\Program Files\WindowsApps

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-10-preview

Lately, I've been quite annoyed at the fact that I can't edit files in C:\Program Files\WindowsApps folder. I've used the takedown command, in elevated CMD, and changed permissions, to allow admins to have full control (I am an admin), and changed owner to Administrators. I can delete files/folders, yet, whenever I try to edit files, or add files, I get the error message "Access is denied." How do I enable creating files and editing files in WindowsApps?

Comment: I don't understand, why does MS have to f*ck up everything? What's wrong with users editing files in this folder?? Pathetic

Answer (score 23):

The `WindowsApps` folder is one of the most heavily protected folders in Windows 10. It contains all the Windows UWP apps, to which Microsoft zealously guards the access.
The protections on this folder may change across Windows versions.

The usual methods of taking ownership and assigning permissions are not enough for this folder, but are still required as first step to gaining access.
After executing them, accessing the folder is now possible for copying, but editing is still blocked. To edit, one needs to save the file elsewhere, and only then replace the original with the edited version.

A further note is that restoring the ownership of the folder to `TrustedInstaller`
is possible without losing the extra permissions that were assigned,
by using the command:

```
icacls "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps" /setowner "NT Service\TrustedInstaller" /t
```

If someone wishes to use an elevated Command Prompt for gaining
access to the folder, then these are the commands :

```
    takeown /F "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps"
    takeown /F "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps" /r /d y
    icacls "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps" /grant Administrators:F
    icacls "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps" /grant Administrators:F /t
```

I also note that permission problems can be avoided by using the following
commands before and after changing permissions to completely
restore the original permissions :

```
icacls "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps" /save WindowsApps.acl
icacls "%ProgramFiles%" /restore WindowsApps.acl
```

To complement the poster's remark about restoring
the original permissions on the folder while not having saved
these permissions before starting, this is done by entering in an elevated
Command Prompt (cmd) the command :

```
icacls "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps" /q /c /t /reset
```

If the command does not work, it needs to be redone from a Windows boot CD/USB,
as explained in the post
[Reset default ACLs for C:\Program Files\WindowsApps](https://superuser.com/questions/1288014/reset-default-acls-for-c-program-files-windowsapps):

1. Follow the instructions on this page to create the
   [Windows Installation Media](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15088/windows-create-installation-media)
2. Boot from the USB/CD, click "Repair my computer" upon reaching the *Install* button
3. Select *Troubleshoot*, then *Command Prompt*
4. Your current drive `C:` will be the boot media, with your Windows system disk
   likely in `D:`, so verify using `dir D:`, and if not, then search for the
   right drive-letter
5. Using the drive letter you just found (maybe `D:\`), issue the command:

   ```
   icacls "D:\Program Files\WindowsApps" /q /c /t /reset
   ```
6. Wait for the operation to complete, and check the output for errors
7. Reboot.

Comment: Interesting, in my case "The usual methods of taking ownership" already gives me the right to change and create files/folders (Windows 10 Pro). In what specific case isn't it enough?

Comment: @Albin: It's not enough since Windows has built-in protections specially for this folder that can only be worked around, not removed.

Comment: @Albin Maybe you are not using Windows 1803 or 1809, because these version don't allow any file edits even when you have taken complete control, I will test these steps asap.

Comment: @harrymc I just checked, I'm using version 1803 on my testsystem. I also double checked, I tried to edit and save an (exiting, not created by me) xlm file. It works without problems.

Comment: @Albin: I don't know the settings on your computer and I cannot diagnose, Microsoft does not furnish any information about this.

Comment: @harrymc There are no "additional" settings. It's a updated but otherwise untouched Win10pro System, I just changed the ownership. Also after reapplying the ownership, the user keeps the access using the IU-methode, you don't necessarily have to use the command line method to keep you're access.

Comment: @Albin: Everything is possible where Microsoft is concerned.

Comment: :'D anyway let me know the results of you're test

Comment: So I tested by just using `icacls /save` then `icacls reset` then `icacls /restore` but that made the apps unusable too. Something is getting broken / not restored. I'm stuck in figuring out how to make the apps work again after gaining access to the folder, even without modification. I do have developer mode enabled so I should be somehow able to launch the apps outside of WindowsApps folder, I just don't know how.. but developers should be able to test their apps,  right..? I ran all commands from a "Trusted Installer" CommandPrompt (RunAsTi64) because running it from admin wouldn't work.

Comment: Doing it from a boot CD/USB might work better.

Comment: I didn't want the bounty to go to waste and as this is the most comprehensive answer I gave it here.

Comment: @Gizmo: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: no, It seems microsoft encrypts the files on the disk using a key, that is only aquired when launching the app from the ms-store. I don't know how to copy this key. Obviously there is no documentation for that.

Comment: @Gizmo: Obviously.

Comment: I'm on Windows 1909 and these steps apparently no longer work for allowing edit access to the files under WindowsApps. I can see and read them, but not edit or create.

Comment: (And nor can I copy or move files into WindowsApps.)

Comment: @SaudAljaffer, I voted to reject your edit because ir should be an answer, and the script should be part of it instead of being a link.

Answer (score 3):

Level of difficulty [extremely advanced].

On Win 10 (almost latest version), I read Harry’s original post and chose to start with the backup:

1. Click Start
2. Type “cmd” and wait, don’t hit enter yet.
3. Click “run as administrator”
4. Type:

   ```
    cd \Progra~1 and hit enter
   ```
5. Backup permissions:

   ```
    icacls "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps" /save WindowsApps.acl
   ```

I then continued with Harry’s guidance:

[Still]...an elevated Command Prompt for gaining access to the folder (but for grant I started with just my App, which had special settings it wanted me to update for EyeTV 64-bit):

```
takeown /F "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps"
takeown /F "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps" /r /d y
icacls "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps\GENIA...<-your App name" /grant Administrators:F
icacls "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps\GENIA...<-your App name" /grant Administrators:F /t
```

I was conservative
I changed view settings:
Select View > Options > Change folder and search options.
Select the View tab and, in Advanced settings, select Show hidden files, folders, and drives and OK.

I then followed Albin’s post above to get more control and remove inheritance (not completely, but make it individual) on WindowsApps:

![Albin’s post images]

I now right click WindowsApps folder in C:\Program Files and unhide and uncheck read only.
Also gave myself, Admin, Full Control see Albin for permissions, and Apply

Then at elevated cmd:

```
icacls "file" /setowner "NT Service\\TrustedInstaller" /T /C
```

I went to my Genia folder in WindowsApps and copied the file I wanted to desktop, edited it and copied it back to just the Program Files folder (with Administrator confirmation).

Back in elevated command prompt I deleted the old file I wanted to change:
del “filename.ini”.
Then I got Linus Torvalds Git app for windows, from wikipedia
I Installed git-bash, then ran that “right-click” as administrator.
Copied the file using that and got a 0 byte empty file and error, but it did not break my apps, and proved write capability.

I got Ubuntu 12 and used Rufus in Freedos/mbr mode to make a bootable USB from Ubuntu AMD 64 or 32 iso, and BIOS boot to my UEFI USB.
In test mode I used The folder icon > Win10 “whatever your disk is called” to mount my drive.
In logo icon (top left), search terminal, click and navigate via:

```
cd /media/Win10/Program\ Files > enter
cat filename.ini > WindowsApps/GENIA.../Transponders/filename.ini
```

I unmounted (ejected) Win10 back in folder view.
Shutdown (top right button), reboot.
Wait for dots about ten times.
Remove USB when prompted, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Test it out in Windows.
My App now works right, with settings updated.

I tried elevated cmd prompt:

```
icalcs %ProgramFiles% /restore WindowsApps.acl
```

No success, so I did:

```
icacls "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps" /q /c /t /reset
```

I then followed Albin’s post above to remove control and inheritance on WindowsApps:

![Albin’s post images]

Even though it was there, Made myself owner again. I Added Administrators > check Names.
Added new user permission, check names;
Gave myself just read & execute, list folder contents, read on a second Administrator entry;
And deleted full control entry for me.
I changed owner back

NT Service\TrustedInstaller > check names
Becomes TrustedInstaller

I then hit apply and close out.
My apps still work.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this myself nonetheless:

From an administrator command prompt the following command will copy the WindowsApps package folder (or any folder within):

```
robocopy /B /E /COPY:DAT D:\WindowsApps\xxx D:\MyTargetDir
```

This will copy the `WindowsApps\xxx` package folder on `D:\` to `MyTargetDir` folder on `D:\`. This works because the /B option tells Windows to use the Backup token which ignores any permissions or limitations / policies.

After that the files need to be decrypted:

```
cipher /D /S:D:\MyTargetDir
```

Then the files can be edited.

Remove the original folder (or rename it):

```
mv D:\WindowsApps\xxx D:\WindowsApps\xxx_
```

And then copy back the edited files:

```
robocopy /B /E /COPY:DAT D:\MyTargetDir D:\WindowsApps\xxx
```

HOWEVER: Note, I still haven't figured out how to make the edited app start, as for now Windows Store will return errors for the apps in these folders as soon as the permissions are changed. Changing them back won't work.

Comment: How did you're WindowsApps-Folder change from "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps" to "D:\WindowsApps" in comparison to the original quesiton?

Comment: @Albin you can go to `Settings -> Storage -> Change where new content is stored -> New apps will save to` to separately install a new app on for example D:\ so experimenting is possible without destroying your original WindowsApps folder.

Comment: ah, ok, I thought you managed to move the whole WindowsApps somehow. In Order for the store not to show errors you need to restore the metadata of the files (like security settings etc.) to the original values then it should work without any errors. Using DAT as copy parameters doesn't copy "all" of them, so you need to reapply them or use different copy parameters (look [here](https://techjourney.net/robocopy-syntax-command-line-switches-and-examples/))

Comment: Yeah I copied DAT specifically so it wouldn't interfere with editing the files at the copied location because DATSU would also restrict editing.

Comment: I see, but then you have to reapply the security settings of the files (and possibly whatever other metadata gets lost during copying) in order to get rid of the error (anyway I like you're approach, very creative). Maybe you could try to copy the files with all the matadata and then try changing the ownership manually via UI or Commandline? What happens if you try to access the files after the change?

Comment: @Albin, look, taking ownership is not going to work and if that's the case for you then I don't know what it is or how that is possible. I Keep getting Access is denied errors even when I'm TrustedInstaller or SYSTEM. I leave this video here as proof (10 minutes): https://streamable.com/ql32s The other problem is that whenever anything is changed to the WindowsApps folder, any apps refuse to launch that are within that folder. Restoring permissions doesn't work either. Sorry the video is so "slow", I was doing your instructions EXACTLY.

Comment: For a game like forza demo even robocopy /b won't work.. so can't even mod the handling or textures

Comment: Thanks for the vid, I replyed in the comment under my answer, so we don't have several threads going.

Comment: "I still haven't figured out how to make the edited app start," So you haven't really solved your problem. Please don't post answers that don't work.

Comment: I made a script to restore all the crap required for the apps to launch again: https://github.com/AgentRev/WindowsAppsUnfukker

Comment: even with `robocopy /b` I'm getting "Access is denied" as well :/

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution: you have to change the ownership of the files/folders. [Here you can see the description including screenshots](http://justinangel.net/ReverseEngineerWin8Apps) (there's already a copy on [superuser](https://superuser.com/a/498776/201818) as well). I just tried it on Win10 Creating/Editing/Deleting Files is possible.

If you want to reverse the ownership change you can find a [description here](https://www.askvg.com/guide-how-to-restore-trustedinstaller-as-default-owner-of-a-file-or-folder-in-windows/). After changing it back you're user will still have access to the folder, removing all other security changes (like changed permissions) that were made during the ownership change will fix that to it's original state.

**Important:** In some cases the Store (or the Apps) wont function after changing the ownership and changing it back, unless you remove "all" changes not just the ownership. So make sure to create a system restore point unless you know exactly what you are doing!

---

**Here's a copy of the description to change the ownership:**

1. Type in `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps` in the Windows Explorer address bar and hit enter.

   [image: Enter path]
2. Observe in shock and dismay the system dialog saying you don’t own a folder on your own machine. Hit "Continue."

   [image: Denied]
3. After hitting "Continue," you’ll be confronted by the following dialog:

   [image: Denied again]

   Do not hit "Close"—instead click the "security tab" link.
4. In the following system dialog click "Advanced."

   [image: Properties]
5. Click the "Change" link in the owner security field.

   [image: Change]
6. Add in your Live ID or Windows 8 user name to the "Select User or Group" system dialog.

   [image: Add user]
7. Click "OK," "OK," and "OK."

   [image: Done]

Comment: This is not an answer to the question as this does not work. You seem to assume that the WindowsApps folder seems to honor the ACLs, which it does not (entirely). Download "Chess Free" to for example D:\ so you don't screw up your real WindowsApps folder. Do your steps and you won't be able to edit the game files. I will only give ab ounty to a solution that successfully allows me to edit files. Or even just copy them to my own desktop. This answer does not work for that. Copying a folder from WindowsApps to Desktop will yield (on a single pc not connected to a domain) and error.

Comment: @Gizmo what do you mean by "download Chess Free for example D:\"?? Changing the ownership allows me to create new Files/Folders as well as edit existing Files/Folders or copy them to the desktop etc. That's what you want to do, right? If it doesn't work for you, could you please explain what happens after you apply this solution and, for example, try to create a Folder or File in "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps" (or any subfolder)?

Comment: @Gizmo I'm unable to check reproduce you're problem. This method allows me to edit existing files (previously existing to the change) as well as adding new files as well as copy existing files to a different location. Could you please specify you're problem? What exactly is the error message? Thank you!

Comment: I keep getting "Access is denied".

Comment: @Gizmo Thanks for the upload. I looked at the error message, it says that you didn't take ownership of the object. There could be several reasons for this (for example that the ownership wasn't transferred to all sub-objekts correctly). Before you edit the file could you check if you have ownership and you're username is listed under "permissions" (for read, write, list etc. access) as well?

Comment: My account has "Full Control" of all objects (via inheritance)

Comment: @well, s.th. still didn't work with changing the ownership if you are still getting the same message. If you check the ownership of the file directly what does it say? Maybe you could make a screenshot of the "Advanced Security settings" for the file you want to edit (make sure you scroll down so you're user can be seen as well)?!

Comment: Yep, this just doesn't work, at all.  You can view the files, but not edit them.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft It worked on my test system (Win 10 Pro 1803) maybe it does not on newer versions. Which Windows version are you using? Are you sure you did it right? Which permissions did you set, for which user and which user are you using to edit?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested all solution to edit file for Age of Empire IV, even the linux one !
But it doesn't work, the directory is corrupted ... we can just move it to the trash :/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Agreed. Better to move the entire Window$ to trash.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen and tried many ways, but only one method has never disappointed me until now: [MoveFileEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefileexa) with the flag MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT. It executes the copy operation early during the next reboot.

If you don't want to write a program (C++, C#), you can do it with a PowerShell script. For example, to copy "test.txt" from C:\temp into MSPaint's WindowsApp directory:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
 
    public static class MyKernel32
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern bool MoveFileEx(
            String lpExistingFileName,
            String lpNewFileName,
            uint dwFlags);
    }
"@


[MyKernel32]::MoveFileEx("C:\Temp\test.txt", "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.MSPaint_2022.2203.1037.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe\test.txt", 5)
```

This will schedule the "move" operation for the next reboot.

Pay attention to the following:

1. Since this is a "move" operation, the file will really be moved, meaning it will no longer exist in C:\temp.
2. MoveFileEx cannot work across drives. Both paths (source and target) must be located on the same drive (maybe even on the same partition, I'm not sure)

Deleting files from WindowsApps directory seems to be easier. It can usually be done from Windows Explorer started as administrator. Or use Sysinternal's [psexec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) to start a DOS-prompt under System-account:

```
psexec -s cmd.exe
```

This also gives you a lot of power. But unfortunately, usually not enough to simply use the "copy" command.

Answer (score -2):

I found a simple solution, after try a lot of things, I discover a problem in the folder name (special character like ~), try rename the main app folder to a simple name like "folder1" (save the original name in notepad before), copy or replace the files and come back the main app name folder to original name.

Other thing, look if windows "LongPath" register is enabled, why sometimes subfolder have more than 255 characters

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.