# How to reset default WindowsApps permissions per-app instead of for the folder

Tags: command-line, powershell, permissions, command-line-arguments

I seem to have messed up my `WindowsApps` folder badly, but managed to restore it using a [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/1288014/reset-default-acls-for-c-program-files-windowsapps). This fixed and added the proper permissions for the `WindowsApps` folder **ITSELF**, but not the individual apps. Whenever I run any app (except [Powershell](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9MZ1SNWT0N5D) and [Powershell Preview](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9P95ZZKTNRN4) strangely), it throws this at me:

[image: File not found]

It shows this for every Microsoft Store app I use, and when checking permissions it seems that every file/folder in `WindowsApps` has only `Read` permissions for `Users`, which means I can no longer execute any files, but I can view them in their directory.

I am not sure if this is possible, but if you manage to help me, I will be eternally grateful. If it is impossible to reset all apps, then I can manage fixing a handful instead.

EDIT: I tried deleting and reinstalling the apps in question, but the problem still persists

Comment: You should not mess with the Windows Apps folder.  Either fix the ones you need or back up and reinstall Windows.

Comment: I'm ready to reinstall, but I am waiting for a possible solution first

Comment: I don't think there is a solution that will fix these permissions that doe not reinstall Windows.

Comment: John is indeed correct, there isn't a solution to this problem, which is the reason the permissions on this folder shouldn't be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft Apps folder is heavily secured and messing with it damages the registry. This is the reason an ordinary solution does not exist.

The only practical way to correct the issue is to back up and reinstall Windows.

Then, do stay entirely away from damaging registry entries.  There is  fair trail of reinstalled systems in here because of messing with the Apps folder.

Comment: Please explain how these files are somehow connected with the registry.

Comment: The fold er  (as I noted) is heavily secured and we are not able to change the permissions on the folder. When you did that, you damaged the registry. It is most unlikely you can repair the damage so you must rebuild.

Comment: I managed to fix it by running recovery media and removing apps but not personal files, which fixed the problem without a full reset