# How can I clear out unneeded folders in the C:\Program Files\WindowsApps folder?

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, file-permissions, storage

According to the hard drive disk space analyzer [WizTree](https://antibody-software.com/web/software/software/wiztree-finds-the-files-and-folders-using-the-most-disk-space-on-your-hard-drive/), the folder  `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps` is taking up a ton of storage space. Most of the folders there are from pre-installed software, mostly games. I want to delete the unneeded folders.

[image: WizTree's analysis]

I was able to enter the `WindowsApps` folder, which previously I didn't have permission to enter. I updated my permissions to have everything except `Special permissions` (which I doubt is needed).

[image: My current permissions for the WindowsApps folder]

When I try to delete one of the folders I'm asked for Administrator permission, which I approve. Then, however, I'm told I need permission from myself to make changes to the folder.

[image: Need permission from myself]

One thing I noticed was that there was a difference in the security groups between the `WindowsApps` and the folder I'm trying to delete: the one I'm trying to delete has a `Users (DESKTOP-WWWWWWW\Users)` group which only has `Read` and `Special permissions` permissions.

When I tried to use the terminal to delete the folders it output `Access is denied` after me confirming that I wanted to delete each folder. [Here's the output.](https://pastebin.com/raw/212Qwved)

How can I delete folders in the `WindowsApps` directory?

Edit: Version 10.0.17134, Build 17134. I was looking at Add/Remove Programs as well as the Control Panel menu for programs.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't think there's a problem with WizTree; it and the folder properties in Windows Explorer show the same size.

Comment: @Ramhound Unfortunately uninstalling them wasn't enough for me, they aren't listed under installed programs but the folders are still there. I'll take a look at the question you linked, thanks! I'll also try installing/uninstalling the programs that still have folders, maybe that will help.

Comment: To anyone who stumbles upon this, the solution here worked perfectly. I was able to delete any folder I wanted, clearing up ~20gb of space from "uninstalled" programs! https://superuser.com/a/1365110/1076943