# Why Are Our Microsoft Universal Windows Platform Static Software Applications Vanishing?

Tags: windows-10, security, debug, users, uwp

***Edit***: This Issue has been - fortunately or unfortunately - solved by Yet Another Clean Install, as it has been specified toward the end of the text of this question.

Still, as advised by @Ramhound, we need to specify the fact that before noticing the manifestation of this Issue, the User Account Control had been disabled long time ago. For a certain period of time, still our *Microsoft* *Windows* *Universal Windows Platform* Static Software Applications have been working quite all right.

Now begins the Original Text of the Question.

Our *Microsoft* *Windows* *Universal Windows Platform* Static Software Applications have started vanishing today after their launch into execution.

We have already fully updated twice the *Microsoft* *Windows* **10** Operating System today. Everything has been working out smoothly. We would not blame the applying of any Software Update Packages this time.

What we have done has been to take the ownership of the `WindowsApps` Folder ourselves. It would have been enough just to add only Read Access to ourselves, as we just wanted to read a certain piece of data from within it.

Instead of doing that, we have gotten greedy and we have taken ownership of the whole Folder with all of its Sub-Folders and Files. We do not know how to set it back, as we cannot select the `TrustedInstaller` User when we have to.

[image: The <code>WindowsApps</code> Folder]

[image: The Current Erroneous Owner]

[image: Finding the <code>TrustedInstaller</code> User]

[image: The Inability to Find the <code>TrustedInstaller</code> User]

***Update***:

Great answer, @harrymc. It did fix our Issue with the `TrustedInstaller` User.

[image: Resetting the Ownership of the <code>WindowsApps</code> Folder]

We also had to check the following check-mark and to recursively apply the ownership to the Sub-Folders and to the Files within the `WindowsApps` Folder.

[image: The Check-Mark for the Recursive Resetting of the Ownership]

It would be great if you could improve your answer so that everything is automatically done recursively.

However, this did not solve our Issue. We have renamed the title of this question.

We might not be blamable at all. Other than this erroneous setting of the ownership of the `WindowsApps` Folder to ourselves, we have not done anything *obviously* wrong to the machine today. We have to imagine that the two Software Update Packages that we have applied today have messed up something related to the *Microsoft* *Windows* *Universal Windows Platform* Static Software Applications.

***Behavior:***

1. Some *Microsoft* *Windows* *Universal Windows Platform* Static Software Applications, such as the *Microsoft* *Windows* *Calc* Static Software Application or the *Microsoft* *Windows* *Skype* Static Software Application, are appearing shortly for a few seconds and then they are simply vanishing.
2. Some *Microsoft* *Windows* *Universal Windows Platform* Static Software Applications, such as the *RCS-RDS-Digi* *Digi.Online* Static Software Application, are processing something for a few tens of seconds and then they are simply vanishing.

***Update***:

What we have done other than messing up the ownership of the `WindowsApps` Folder has been to uninstall a certain number (around six) Static Software Applications - not only *Microsoft* *Windows* *Universal Windows Platform* Static Software Applications - *before* applying the two Software Update Packages.

Maybe the *Microsoft* *Windows* *Installer* had *already* gotten broken after the uninstallation of those around six Static Software Applications.

We have also applied the `Get-AppXPackage | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}` *Microsoft* *Windows* *PowerShell* One-Liner. It has been working out smoothly, except for `Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost` and for `Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost`.

[image: Microsoft Windows PowerShell One-Liner for Re-Registering Static Software Applications]

However, the *Microsoft* *Windows* *Universal Windows Platform* Static Software Applications are still vanishing.

To sum up, here is the number of potential mistakes that we have committed:

1. The uninstallation of around six Static Software Applications - not only *Microsoft* *Windows* *Universal Windows Platform* Static Software Applications - from the *Apps and Features* Pane. Maybe they have been just too many at a time. Maybe they should have been followed by a reboot of the machine.
2. The erroneous setting of the ownership for ourselves for the `WindowsApps` Folder.
3. The installation of two Software Update Packages. Maybe they have been just too many per day. Each of them have been automatically followed by a reboot of the machine.

***Update***:

Just to make sure that we did it correctly, we have rerun the `icacls "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps" /setowner "NT Service\TrustedInstaller" /t` One-Liner with the `/t` Switch in it.

[image: The Recursive Restoring of the Ownership]

The behavior is persisting.

***Update***:

Just to double-check everything, we have also rerun the *Microsoft* *Windows* *PowerShell* One-Liner, this time with the `-AllUsers` Switch:

`Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}`

This time we have got lots of Error Messages.

For instance, once it was searching for the `C:\AppXManifest.xml` File and it was complaining that it does not exist. Therefore, the `InstallLocation` Variable was probably not set for that Static Software Application.

[image: The Microsoft Windows PowerShell One-Liner Rerun with the -AllUsers Switch]

What we *did* notice today has been the fact that the *Microsoft* *Windows* *Edge* Web-Browser *is* working. It is located in the `SystemApps` Folder.

So, indeed, we might had messed up everything. Possible scenario:

1. The erroneous ownership setting of the `WindowsApps` Folder has made further modifications to these Static Software Applications impossible by the `TrustedInstaller` User.
2. The two Software Package Updates have modified something in an erroneous way, without complaining. The Success Message presented to the User was "*You are up to date*".
3. Even after the restoration of the correct ownership of the `WindowsApps` Folder to the `TrustedInstaller` User, these Static Software Applications are no longer working.

***Update***:

Millions of thanks, guys, for your help, but apparently troubleshooting this Issue is going nowhere and it is working extremely, extremely slow.

We might have to reinstall the whole thing sometimes.

Just to note the output of the patch suggested by @harrymc, this is how far we have gone:

1. The Troubleshooter of the *Microsoft* *Windows Store* Static Software Applications does not want to wake up itself from its own slumber that easily.

[image: Weird Permissions of msdt.exe]

2. Awakened in an administrative way, it is also requiring a passkey that should be given by a support professional.

[image: PassKey Requirement]

We feel that we have been here before. We have debated [this question](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/failure-while-installing-the-microsoft-windows/47e9bd09-def5-47b1-8ae9-b6fad1b9c68c) for more than nine months and ten days. Its answer has been a simple Clean Install of the machine.

So we have to give some credit to @John also.

***Closure***:

We have finally closed this Issue after another Hellish Week-End.

We have been supported by Al Kim Repelliano or something from `support.microsoft.com`. We have been able to identify together the fact that during the subsequent manual uninstallations of around six Static Software Applications (not only *Microsoft* *Windows* *Universal Windows Platform* Static Software Applications) that we have performed on Saturday, something has gone wrong.

It might not have been the corruption of the *Microsoft* *Windows* *Installer*. Something else might have gone wrong. Al Kim Repelliano has shown us something, but we have been unable to grasp it that fast. These guys are moving *way* too fast.

We have decided together that the best solution was to revert the Operating System back to a certain System Restore Point that had happened to take place just before the manual uninstallation of the *Backup and Sync from Google* Static Software Application.

Al Kim Repelliano has ensured us that everything will work out smoothly. However, after the restoration of the System Restore Point, the Blue Screen of Death has come back into our world.

We have attempted to boot the machine from either of three (!) System Repair Disks. None of them has booted the machine, for unknown reasons.

We have rebooted the machine using an Universal Serial Bus Flash Drive. We have attempted to apply the *Repair* Option, as advised by @John. For some unknown reason, the System Image Restoration Operation that was supposed to use a System Image located on another Universal Serial Bus External *Winchester* Hard Disk Drive has failed with a stupid Error Message, although the System Image had been performed quite recently on the same machine.

[image: An Error Message that Has Prevented the System Image Restoration]

After a while, one of the three System Repair Disks has miraculously started to work. It has been able to boot the machine. Using the Universal Serial Bus Flash Drive that contains the Installation Kit of the *Microsoft* *Windows* **10** Operating System, we have been able to delete the entire Operating System Software Primary Partition and then to recreate it after a few attempts (!).

Therefore, no *Repair* Option has ever been working this time. The Solution to this Problem has been to perform yet another Clean Install.

It is interesting that we had the inspiration to copy the `C:\Users\DOBRE\Documents\` Folder to the `Internal_Data` (`D:`) Software Primary Partition *before* accepting Al Kim Repelliano's speedy urge to apply the restoration of the System Restore Point.

We would like to thank @harrymc, @Ramhound and @John for their patient support that they have been offering to us during the manifestation of this Issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Editing/Creating files in C:\Program Files\WindowsApps](https://superuser.com/questions/940693/editing-creating-files-in-c-program-files-windowsapps)

Comment: This could have been it. However, after applying @harrymc's answer, still my _Microsoft_ _Windows_ _Universal Windows Platform_ static software applications are disappearing after a short while spent in execution.

Comment: Try the Repair Install as I suggested below. Use the "Keep Everything" option to start with and it is a reliable process

Comment: What exactly is a "Microsoft Windows Universal Windows Platform static software application"?  If UWP applications are starting an immediately existing that is an indication that UAC has been disabled on the system.

Comment: True. However, they used to work even during the disabling of the User Access Control.

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai - They shouldn’t have worked but you made no mention you turned off UAC completely

Comment: Yes, indeed. I had turned off the User Access Control completely. Why should not they have worked?

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai - UWP applications require UAC to be enabled in order to function.  You should enable UAC, see if the behavior exhibits itself, with UAC being enabled.  Edit/Update your question with this vital information.  What exactly is the "installation kit" you speak of?

Comment: After the Failure in the applying of the System Restore Point and in the applying of the Operating System Image, we have had no choice other than to reinstall the whole Operating System using an Universal Serial Bus Flash Drive that contains the Software Installation Kit of the _Microsoft_ _Windows_ _**10**_ Operating System that is available online. Now everything is working. It is funny that you are mentioning that the User Access Control has to be enabled in order to have the _Universal Windows Platform_ Static Software Applications working. We were using them somehow with it disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried to do what you have done here. Try running a Windows 10 Repair install to see if you can correct this.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button, select Save.
Create a USB Windows Installation key and then run Setup on the USB Key. 
This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Comment: This solution should it be followed.  It is filled with pitfalls, if you use this solution, your desktop based applications will be uninstalled.  I would run the commands in the proposed duplicate instead.  This answer should absolutely not be followed it is the incorrect solution to your problem

Comment: I am sorry, @John, but I have to agree with @Ramhound here. As you can see above, I have 2.19 Giga-Bytes of Data inside the `WindowsApps` Folder contained in 13,925 Files and 2,104 Folders. I do not want to risk my neck and to use a _Repair_ Procedure that might do *absolutely* anything.

Comment: I appreciate your concern (of course I would have backed up first), but the next course of action would be to back up completely and install Windows again. I do understand that is distasteful.

Comment: Of course, reinstalling everything might be another enlightening experience, but I still hope that something might arise that could spare me of that. I just hope that I do not get very soon to the last step of complete reinstallation.

Comment: @John - Why would anyone reinstall Windows, when there is a solution to this problem, that does not involve reinstalling Windows.

Comment: What solution do you see here?

Comment: @John - Diagnose the real problem and submit a solution to that problem.  Author disabled UAC, which means UWP applications would not function, which is by design.

Answer (score 0):

You may reset `TrustedInstaller` as owner of the `WindowsApps` by entering the
following command in an elevated Command Prompt:

```
icacls "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps" /setowner "NT Service\TrustedInstaller" /t
```

For more information on how to safely change ownership of system folders
or files, see
[this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1365110/8672)
of mine.

To re-register all the Microsoft Store applications, see the article
[How to Reinstall and Re-register All Built-in Windows Apps in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3175-reinstall-re-register-apps-windows-10-a.html).

If there is still corruption in the Microsoft Store:

- Run the Microsoft Store troubleshooter in
  *Settings > Update & Security > Troubleshoot > Windows Store Apps >
  Run the troubleshooter*.
- Reset the Microsoft Store in
  *Settings > Apps > Microsoft Store > Advanced options > Reset*.
- Clear the Store cache by running `wsreset.exe`
- Re-register the Microsoft Store by running PowerShell as Admin
  and entering the following command
  `"& {$manifest = (Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.WindowsStore).InstallLocation + '\AppxManifest.xml' ; Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $manifest}"`

The above may lose you the UWP apps that you installed yourself.

Comment: Perfect. It might help other people.

Comment: Good point. Maybe it is an older issue that is now just showing its full teeth. A while ago - maybe even a few years, I was using the _Microsoft_ _Windows_ _Mail_ _Microsoft_ _Universal Windows Platform_ static software application. During the writing of a very nice, beautiful and colorful Electronic Mail Message, the application was simply vanishing. No Error Message. No Curse. No Punishment. Just leaving me high and dry. Now, let us take the instance of the _Microsoft_ _Windows_ _Calc_ application. It starts. It prints a rectangle with a handheld calculator on it. Then - vanishing tricks.

Comment: This may be corruption in the Microsoft Store, so I added a part for repairing it.