# How to reinstall OneNote for Windows 10 without using the Microsoft Store?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, installation, microsoft-onenote

I am working with a bunch of computers that were imaged by someone who removed all the built-in Windows 10 apps -- including the Microsoft Store app.  Whoever removed them didn't just uninstall them with a simple `Remove-AppxPackage` command; they actually *de-provisioned* those apps entirely with `Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage`, so the package files are not even on the drives anymore to be reinstalled via `Add-AppxPackage`.

I've figured out how to get Skype and OneDrive back (standalone versions of those can be downloaded from Microsoft's web site), but I cannot figure out how to get OneNote back.  The standalone package on Microsoft's site as well as the version that comes with Office 365 is OneNote 2016, which is not the same version.  All the Googling I do on the subject just keeps regurgitating Microsoft's instructions on how to get it from the app store.  I really do not want to have to reinstall Windows from scratch on all these computers.

**What I've tried:**
Most of the users are on 1803 or 1809, but upgrading to 1903 doesn't resolve anything.

I tried copying the OneNote package from a Windows 10 ISO and reinstalling it with `Add-AppxPackage -register <path to AppxManifest.xml> -DisableDeveloperMode`, but it barfs back at me that `AppxManifest.xml is not in the package root.`  This happens even when I copy the files to %PROGRAMFILES%\WindowsApps (which is not easy to do).

I tried using `Add-AppxProvisionedPackage`, but this command requires a `.appx` or `.main` file, which doesn't exist in a stock Windows image (and I don't know how to obtain the OneNote.appx file either).

I then tried manually forcing it by copying the files AND registry settings off a reference PC.  This time, `Add-AppxPackage` says it installed it and I get a Start Menu icon for it, but it doesn't work (the OneNote splash screen comes up briefly before disappearing again).

I can't believe Microsoft allows you to paint yourself into a corner like this.

Is there any way to restore OneNote?

Please note, the solution has to be scriptable, so doing a repair/refresh of Windows 10 is out (I may as well just re-image all these computers and do it right at that point).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can generate links to the APPX files provided the by the Microsoft Store URL on [AdGuard](https://store.rg-adguard.net/). These download links are directly from Microsoft.

---

**OP Update for future readers:**
Once the .appx or .appxbundle file is downloaded, it can be added back into the package root with the following PowerShell command:

```
add-appxprovisionedpackage -online -packagepath <path to appx file> -skiplicense
```

Answer (score 2):

- **Disclaimer:** I have tested the following procedure in a virtual machine.
  So, it may not work in real environment. Also the procedure may require admin
  permissions to take ownership of folder. Make sure you have the same version of
  Windows 10 ISO file which is already installed.
- **Procedure:**

  - Mount the same version of Windows 10 ISO file. Assume the mounted drive
    letter is `F:\`. Now detect the index matched with installed Windows 10 edition.
    Run this command in Command Prompt as administrator:

```cmd
dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:F:\sources\install.wim
```

For example, Windows 10 Pro will be in `Index : 6`.

- Open `F:\sources\install.wim` file in [7ZIP](https://www.7-zip.org/). Goto the index number
  (here 6) > Program Files > Windows Apps and extract the `OneNote` and `VCLibs`
  folders. Folder version may be different.

```powershell
Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.26706.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.26706.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.Office.OneNote_16001.11126.20076.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.Office.OneNote_16001.11126.20076.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

- Paste those folder in the actual installed Windows 10
  `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\` folder. This may require admin permissions
  to take ownership of that folder. Follow [this procedure](https://www.howtogeek.com/301768/how-to-take-ownership-of-files-and-folders-in-windows/).
- Run these following commands in Powershell to register those Appx using
  [Add-AppxPackage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/add-appxpackage) cmdlet with the full path of `ApxManifest.xml` file:

```powershell
Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -register "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.26706.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml"
Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -register "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.26706.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml"
Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -register "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Office.OneNote_16001.11126.20076.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml"
Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -register "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Office.OneNote_16001.11126.20076.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml"
```

Comment: Taking ownership of WindowsApps like that causes later problems with Windows Update, so to be avoided. Use rather [this procedure](https://superuser.com/a/1365110/8672) to save and restore the original ownership.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @Biswapriyo worked for me for recovering OneNote for Windows 10 with Windows 10 Home 2H22.

One thing that I modified is I only copied the OneNote folders and not the VCLibs.

```
Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -register "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Office.OneNote_16001.12026.20112.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxMetadata\AppxBundleManifest.xml"
Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -register "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Office.OneNote_16001.12026.20112.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml"
```

At this point, the application is installed but won't open.

After that, I had to use the Windows Store to update the app.

Finally, the application now works fine.

I hope this helps.