# How To Reinstall Staged Apps?

Tags: windows-10

I accidentally removed the Windows Store with Powershell using the Remove-AppxPackage. I see it's still staged with Get-AppxPackage. How can I reinstall it? I cannot find any documentation on commands to reinstall Microsoft.WindowsStore or install from the Windows Store via command line.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and waiting for a solution... http://superuser.com/questions/949112/restore-microsoft-store-application-in-windows-10

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/949112/restore-microsoft-store-application-in-windows-10; cannot vote to close.

Comment: Try re-registering the Store: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/8239-store-re-register-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Unfortunately the command on tenforums isn't working. *edit* I modified the command and managed to get the store working, although it doesn't look like it reinstalled quite correctly as the icon is missing.

Comment: Solution(s) can be found here: http://superuser.com/questions/949112/restore-microsoft-store-application-in-windows-10/949602#949602