# Reinstall Windows Store and got this error from Power Shell

Tags: windows-10, reinstall, windows-store

I uninstalled all the pre-installed Windows apps, including the Store itself. I would like to get it back, and I have been searching around for guides. When I use this command `Get-Appxpackage -Allusers`, there is no `"Microsoft.WindowsStore_*****_8wekyb3d8bbwe"` listed. I went to the folder and check, there was no such folders, so I copied the folders from my other laptop and tried to register the folder using this guide [Restore Microsoft Store application in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/949112/restore-microsoft-store-application-in-windows-10). When I input the command for Windows Store, I got this error, others were fine.

```
Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF3, Package failed          
updates, dependency or conflict
validation. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073CF3)
NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId] d50a2b52-bf9d-000d-
292c-0ad59dbfd101 in the Event Log or use
the command line Get-AppxLog -ActivityID d50a2b52-bf9d-000d-292c-
0ad59dbfd101
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "C:\Program Files\W ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Program File...ppxManifest.xml:String) [Add-AppxPackage], IOExceptio
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand
```

Comment: Have you tried making another local profile and moving everything over and deleting this one? also may not hurt to do a `sfc /scannow` Pretty interested in whats going on here. Should be a fix somewhere.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin After a scan it says "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations."

Comment: If you create a new user does the store show up at all? Within the new user profile? if so then maybe you can install it in your current one.