# Windows Store cache may be damaged

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, troubleshooting, windows-10-v1607, windows-store-app

How to fix this error in windows 10 64 bit Home edition: Windows Store cache may be damaged. 
 "Reset and open Windows Store" 
I have tried but nothing worked.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue? I'm having it too and none of the other solutions (powershell script, wsreset.exe, etc) I've found online work.

Comment: @pseudosavant With Windows 1607 you can also try to reset the Store app directly from the Settings (apps) - anyway, didn't change anything for me so far, still getting this error. Do you have any trouble to update or anything or how does this error manifest for you?

Comment: For Those who are facing this issue, you may already have tried your best to resolve it. Then there are only 2 fixes, either download new copy of windows / reinstall your windows or update to new Creators Update coming very soon.                                                                                            It may occur if u are clearing cache or using CCleaner strongly, or even if your hard disk is getting old.  Please try removing your ram and reinsert it(slot 1 is better), sometimes it would do magic for you.

Comment: I removed & reinserted RAM, downloaded new iso copy from windows, fully formatted my harddrive, newly installed windows, adjusted partitions, and never touched cCleaner, %TEMP%, temp memory. Now it's ultra-responsive, no problems at all.

Comment: If you can uninstall app alone, get a package from [here](https://superuser.com/a/1449292/900431)

Answer (score 0):

The first step to reset Windows Store cache is to run **wsreset** in cmd.
Alternatively you may try to remove Store cache in: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalCache`

If that doesn't help - you need to reinstall Windows Store app.
Start elevated Powershell window (run as administrator) and run in it:

```
Get-AppxPackage *windowsstore* -AllUsers| Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register “$($_.InstallLocation)AppXManifest.xml”}
```

For more details read: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/youll-need-a-new-app-to-open-this-ms-windows-store

Comment: The answer is correct and tested. It's a quite common issue also published on many resources. It's a bad practice for the vote down without arguments.