# Restore/reinstall deleted WindowsStore app in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app

Yesterday I updated Windows to `1709` and now I can't install WSL without WindowsStore, so I'm looking for a way to restore or reinstall the deleted WindoiwsStore app.

WindowsStore app was deleted before release upgrade using:

```
Get-AppxPackage *windowsstore* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online | Where-Object PackageName -like "*windowsstore*" | ForEach { Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online -PackageName $_.PackageName }
```

There now no WindowsStore package folder in `C:\Program files\WindowsApps`, so method:

```
Get-AppxPackage -allusers | where-object PackageFullName -like "*windowsstore*" | foreach {Add-AppxPackage -register ("C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\"+$_.PackageFullName+"\appxmanifest.xml") -DisableDevelopmentMode}
```

don't work.

Comment: Recover the folder from shadowcopy [Accidentally Deleted SystemApps, WindowsApps or Local Packages. How to Recover?](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/restore-deleted-systemapps-windowsapps-packages/), and then run the PowerShell command.

Comment: @w32sh thanks for suggestion, but there is no shadow copy with WindowsStore app. This app removed maoutn ago, and after it i receive two Windows release upgrades.

Comment: @ Slipeer, let's confirm if the provisioned package is exists in your current Windows firstly. Run Get-AppXProvisionedPackage -online >c:\applist.txt powershell command to list all provisioned package.

Comment: @KarenHu i was remove provisioned package WindowsStore I already wrote about this. This packege not listed in command that you provide.

Comment: @Slipeer, you remove it before upgrading, i just want to let you confirm if it available after upgrade, If no, there is no way unless reinstallation.

Comment: @KarenHu it's unavaible after upgrade. I search way to reinstall it.

Comment: @Slipeer, unless you have the full Windows Store provision package, you cannot reinstall it. Thereby I suggest you back up all data and re-clean install.

Comment: After long searching; the simplest solution [here](https://superuser.com/a/1449292/900431), even without provisioning

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this will help but one thing I found out while working on Get-AppxPackages recently is that there is a folder path that contains deleted Windows Apps. Why don't you try running your command with the different folder path and see what you get in return?

"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\DeletedAllUserPackages\Microsoft.BingWeather_4.25.20211.0_neutral_split.scale-150_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppXManifest.xml

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).