# No Microsoft Store, can't reinstall, Troubleshooter says to Sign in, but I am signed in

Tags: windows-10, windows-store, microsoft-store

I have no Microsoft store at all on my Windows 10 Enterprise, Version 1709.

I've read numerous articles on restoring the Microsoft Store, and none of the simple/non-destructive techniques have worked thus far (`GetAppx-package`, `AddAppx-package`, `wsreset`). I haven't reinstalled or reset Windows - I'd rather live without than go through that. (I'm actually on a first Reset already.) [I also haven't tried to find another Windows installation and manually copy things over from there](https://superuser.com/questions/949112/restore-microsoft-store-application-in-windows-10).

I'm hoping that instead the fact that the [Microsoft Store Troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027498/windows-10-run-the-troubleshooter-for-apps) keeps asserting I need to login to Microsoft, when I am already logged in, might indicate a different issue.

[image: Microsoft account required]

Despite being clearly already connected to a Microsoft account:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to logout of your account and then log back into it?  When you say “no Microsoft Store” do you mean it’s not installed or something else.  Please provide all clarification by editing your question

Comment: You need to try the linked solution.  If it works, we need to know, so please try that solution and edit your question

Comment: Try the linked solution of copying the WindowsApps folder from another computer? In my corporate environment, that might not be possible. If that's all that's left, besides reinstall/reset, I'll have to decide whether it's worth pursuing.

Comment: logout/in of Windows? That's does something different here, than rebooting? Pardon my ignorance, and I'm willing to try it if there's any reason it's different from what I've already tried.

Comment: I cannot help you.  I apologize for wasting your time.

Comment: Try to use other Microsoft account. What's the error when you run those command (GetAppx-package, AddAppx-package)?

Comment: No error, the Appx-package commands appear to work, just no Store appear, either with or without reboot.