# Microsoft default Apps not Found on Windows 10 Enterprise, and Can't be Installed

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-store

I just installed Windows 10 Enterprise edition LTSC (OS Build 17763.404), and I can't find my default applications such as "Microsoft Store, Contacts, Calendar, Clock, Or Help Center"

I went through several forums online stating I should open Power shell as Admin and run the following commands then restart the PC :

```
Get-AppXPackage *WindowsStore* -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

But even after that, The Default apps didn't appear, can someone please help ?

Comment: You could try [this](https://superuser.com/a/1449292/900431)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can someone please help?

Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC (Long Term Support Channel) doesn’t include these applications on purpose. They were purposefully removed from this edition of Windows 10.

If you need those applications installed you will need to run Windows 10 Enterprise instead of a LTSC version of Windows 10.

Comment: The command isn’t working because you are not providing a source for the package.  The command you are using assumes the package your attempting to enable exists on the system.  In the case of the built-in UWP applications that isn’t the case for LTSC editions of Windows 10 Enterprise.  While there are ways to extract the package necessary to install it, it involves using third-party tools, from sources I cannot verify.  If you need those applications they need to be installed by your Administrator.  Since Enterprise is volume license this can’t be a case of a personal home license