# How to reinstall restore Windows Store

Tags: windows-10, restore, reinstall, windows-store-app, windows-store

A LOT OF PEOPLE ASKING HOW TO FIX OR RESTORE THE WINDOWS STORE.
This is a fix I made after a lot of stuffing around, should work for people on Windows 10.

1. Download the TakeOwnership file from MediaFire and unzip it:  https://www.mediafire.com/file/6zfp7q7ta7s90qx/TakeOwnership.zip/file
2. Run the file named:  InstallTakeOwnership.reg
3. Navigate to:  C:\Program Files\WindowsApps
4. Right click on the  'WindowsApps'  folder and click on  'Take Ownership'  in the context menu
   (This will give you permission to access the WindowsApps folder)
5. Now open the  'WindowsApps'  folder and find a folder named  'Microsoft.WindowsStore_11909.1001.7.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe'  and open it
   (your folder name may be slighty different)
6. Find the file named  'AppxManifest.xml'  and right click and copy this file
7. Go to  'My Computer'  or  'This PC' and go to your Local Disk (C:)
8. Paste the  'AppxManifest.xml'  file directly in your (C:) directory
9. Open and run 'Command Prompt' as an 'Administrator'.
10. Copy and paste the command:  PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
11. Copy and paste the command:  $manifest = (Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.WindowsStore).InstallLocation + '\AppxManifest.xml' ; Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $manifest
12. Close command prompt and open the Run command by pressing  'Windows Key + R'  and type in  WSReset.exe  and hit enter
13. Wait for the WSReset command to close and restart your PC.
14. Welcome back to the Windows Store!! :)
    Guide created by: Luke Jordan 30091990.. PLEASE LIKE AND SHARE IF IT HELPED YOU!!

Comment: Thanks for the effort in putting in this guide, but please understand we are a Q and A site, posting the answer as question won't work for most people. Instead, you can post a question and then answer your own question.

Comment: Why is it so difficult? `Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}` is enough. Or [Fix problems with apps from Microsoft Store](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/instantanswers/69e76f90-d54c-44cf-9851-c2d1542790db/run-the-troubleshooter-for-windows-apps)

Comment: @LPChip It is "I am a novice programmer, and my virus does not yet know how to reproduce on its own, please start it manually".

Comment: @Akina Sure... Just tried, I'm getting a PEBKAC error.

Comment: Your solution would be better posted as an extra solution on the duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/949112/restore-microsoft-store-application-in-windows-10

Answer (score -2):

1. Download the TakeOwnership file from MediaFire and unzip it:  https://www.mediafire.com/file/6zfp7q7ta7s90qx/TakeOwnership.zip/file
2. Run the file named:  InstallTakeOwnership.reg
3. Navigate to:  C:\Program Files\WindowsApps
4. Right click on the  'WindowsApps'  folder and click on  'Take Ownership'  in the context menu
   (This will give you permission to access the WindowsApps folder)
5. Now open the  'WindowsApps'  folder and find a folder named  'Microsoft.WindowsStore_11909.1001.7.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe'  and open it
   (your folder name may be slighty different)
6. Find the file named  'AppxManifest.xml'  and right click and copy this file
7. Go to  'My Computer'  or  'This PC' and go to your Local Disk (C:)
8. Paste the  'AppxManifest.xml'  file directly in your (C:) directory
9. Open and run 'Command Prompt' as an 'Administrator'.
10. Copy and paste the command:  PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
11. Copy and paste the command:  $manifest = (Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.WindowsStore).InstallLocation + '\AppxManifest.xml' ; Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $manifest
12. Close command prompt and open the Run command by pressing  'Windows Key + R'  and type in  WSReset.exe  and hit enter
13. Wait for the WSReset command to close and restart your PC.
14. Welcome back to the Windows Store!! :)
    Guide created by: Luke Jordan 30091990.. PLEASE LIKE AND SHARE IF IT HELPED YOU!!