# Windows 10: Restore Windows Store App

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app

I've been exploring ways to remove "features" included with Windows 10. One of the ways that I've been looking at is this gem:

```
Get-AppxPackage | Select Name, PackageFullName
Get-AppxPackage | Remove-AppxPackage

Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -online | Select DisplayName, PackageName
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -online | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -online
```

Part one shows the packages... Part two removes them. All of them. *cackles with glee*

The kicker is that this removed the Windows Store app. That *currently* doesn't bother me. I might change my mind and want to use the Windows Store in the future.

How can I restore an app that has been uninstalled and removed from ProvisionedPackages? Can I install via DVD? Download? Email from Bill Gates (that also promises 100$ for forwarding it)?

**Edit #1: Empty Folders**

Looking at other questions/answers, it seems that people expect the files needed to be located in `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps`. From my best guess, the `Get-AppxPackage | Remove-AppxPackage` completely removes the App from that folder. I've looked at other folders (`C:\Windows\SystemApps`, `C:\User\<user>\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsStore*`, etc) and I do not see the application anywhere on the disk.

**Edit #2: Copied app from another machine**

I've copied the Application from another machines `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\...` folder (after taking ownership on both machines and jumping through the proper hoops) (also: I've removed ALL removable apps/provisionedapps EXCEPT Windows Store on that machine and the App Store still opens).

Using [this](https://superuser.com/a/949602/49695):

```
Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register 
    "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Window sStore_2015.722.24.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxMetadata\AppxBundleManifest.xml "
```

The app initially refused to open. I assume that a full reboot cleared it up, because the Store works now.

Comment: Welcome to our team. :) http://superuser.com/questions/949112/restore-microsoft-store-application-in-windows-10

Comment: I'll have to check C:\Program Files\WindowsApps tonight and see if anything is there... I know C:\Windows\SystemApps didn't have it and, like that question, I didn't see App files located that I could place my finger on.

Comment: @Badiboy Yeah, looking through the various App folders I know of (C:\Windows\SystemApps, C:\Program Files\WindowsApps, etc), the Microsoft.WindowsStore folder doesn't exist. Remove-AppxPackage blows it away. I've copied the folder from a VM, reregistered it and it doesn't open.

Comment: That's sad. :( Even with "Add-AppxPackage..." advice from my  question?

Comment: Updated question with my progress, but yeah. I ran out of time to play with it last night, but it registered... and then refused to open (Screen popped up... then closed). I'll toy with it a bit more tonight when I get home.

Comment: @Badiboy Either I'm a liar or time heals all wounds. It seems that copying the folder and waiting (or rebooting?) got the Store working again.

Answer (score 4):

Solution #1: Copy `C:\Program Files\WindowsApp\Microsoft.WindowsStore...\*` from another computer.

1. [Get Access to WindowsApps](https://superuser.com/questions/498768/where-to-find-windows-8-modern-ui-apps-source-code) on both "Broken" computer and a "Working" computer
2. Copy Microsoft.WindowsStore from A to B
3. Use [this](https://superuser.com/a/949602/49695):

   `Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsStore_2015.722.24.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxMetadata\AppxBundleManifest.xml"`
4. Reboot?

When I did this initially the app store closed upon opening. It was the next day, presumably after rebooting, that the Windows Store started working again.

I'd still prefer some sort of "Download the app from Microsoft" solution, but this (copy from another Microsoft computer) is close.

Comment: Good news, bro! I'll try this later because I need to get Win10 distrib for getting "Working" computer...

Comment: My way was longer then yours (http://superuser.com/questions/949112/restore-microsoft-store-application-in-windows-10/951400#951400), but finally I found the sweet home. :)