# Restoring Disabled Modern Apps?

Tags: powershell, windows-10

So I ran the following in my PowerShell:

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage
```

This has made Windows 10 SOOOOOOOOOOOO much better. My question is, what if someday I want to restore some of those disabled apps? Right now, there isn't really anything in the Microsoft Store I want... but who knows, maybe in 6 months, there could be some good stuff in there. How would I go about restoring the Microsoft Store app sometime down the line?

Comment: You would need provide a source to the packages and I assume use Install=AppxPackage but you honestly should have done a backup before you did that command or understand how to reverse it before you did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there are three solutions depending on how deep you are in deleting apps.

[The easiest one.](https://superuser.com/questions/949112/restore-microsoft-store-application-in-windows-10/949602#949602)

[The medium one.](https://superuser.com/questions/949669/windows-10-restore-windows-store-app/950892#950892)

[The longest one.](https://superuser.com/questions/949112/restore-microsoft-store-application-in-windows-10/951400#951400)

Try them one by one until you'll be successfull.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not. That code simply tries to reinstall the existing modern apps that you CAN'T uninstall from the code I posted. This is stuff in the `windows/SystemApps` folder. However, the store app is in the `windows/InfusedApps` folder. So the above code does not install any disabled modern apps.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you loose the Store app. Here is the updated answer.

Comment: @Badiboy - Can't you just summarize what the author should do in this question? If you are just linking to existing answers, why shouldn't this question be closed as a duplicate, of those questions if their answers are the answer?

Comment: @Ramhound: After checking if the solution from link #2 works for me too, I'll reduce the answer and will left only summary.

Comment: @Badiboy - That would be appreciated.

Comment: @Ramhound: updated.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.  *Yes;* This standard of not having link only answers even applies to answers linking to your own answers on this very website.